# OCaml Interpreter: Why my interpreter just execute only one line in my file

Tags: ocaml, interpreter, ocamlyacc, ocamllex

I'm writing an interpreter, using ocamlyacc and ocamllex to compile my parser and lexer.

My problem is that, I have a file calles test, contain 2 commands that are defined in lexer:

```
print a
print b
```

but the interpreter just execute line `print a` only! I know the problem is in main in parser, need to be recursed. I fixed it to be like this (code below) but it still doesn't work.

```
%{  
    open Path
%}

%token <int> INT
%token <string> STRING
%token EOL
%token EOF
%token GET_LINE
%token PRINT

%start main
%type <Path.term> main
%%

main:
    | expr EOL  {$1}
    | expr EOF  {$1}
;


str:
    | STRING { $1 }
    ;
intger:
    | INT {$1 }
    ;
expr:

    | PRINT str  { Print $2 }
    | PRINT str expr  { Print $2 }
    | GET_LINE INT str  { Print_line_in_file ($2, $3) } 
    | GET_LINE INT str expr  { Print_line_in_file ($2, $3) }        
    ;
```

**EDIT**

this is my lexer, i tried to simplify it as much as possible to spot the error.

```
(* File lexer.mll *)

{
    open Parser
}

rule main = parse
    | [' ''\t''\n']     { main lexbuf }
    | "print_line_in_file" { GET_LINE }
    | "print" { PRINT}
    | ['1' - '9']+ as lxm { INT(int_of_string lxm) }
    | ['a'-'z''A'-'Z'] ['a'-'z''A'-'Z''0'-'9']* as lxm { STRING lxm  }
    | eof  {EOF}
```

Main.ml

```
open Path

let _ =
    try
    let filename = Sys.argv.(1) 
    in
        let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel (open_in filename)
        in 
            let result = Parser.main Lexer.main lexbuf
            in
                command result;
                flush stdout
    with Parsing.Parse_error -> print_string "Error! Check syntax";
    flush stdout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on gasche's answer, you need to change your parser definition as follows:

```
%type <Path.term list> main
%%

main:
    | expr EOL main {$1::$3}
    | expr EOF      {[$1]}
    | EOF           {[]}  /* if you want to allow a redundant EOL at the end */
;
```

With your original definition, a single line is considered a complete parse for `main`, that's why your parser stops after that.

Comment: Another problem I have got is "This expression has type Path.term list but an expression was expected of type Path.term". Is there anyway to solve this problem?? this error happens in the main ... On the line `command result` . Is there any tip for me to fix it??

Comment: The parser returns a list of commands now, so you need to do `List.iter command result`, or something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call the parser, it will only parse one expression (that's the type of your starting rule); and it will stop at the end of line (given how you use `EOL` in your grammar). You need to call it several times in a loop if you want to parse several expressions.

Comment: i understand it! The interpreter read all line in the file! But it doesn't execute all of them except the first line in the program! That's what i totally don't understand

Comment: It seems you do not understand yacc, or a bug in the caller which you dont post here. Please, post an entire set of compilable, self contained, simplified codes which can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added them! there is a path file which contain the executable commands written in ocaml, all of them work fine! Please take a look at the question again. Thanks in advanced!